# Multiple conclusions from null hypothesis test?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, hypothesis-testing

Problem: Can we conduct a null hypothesis test (normal distribution, and a 33.3% claim) to determine both if three brands of Hershey's products are **equally popular** (1), **and** if Reese's is **more popular** (2) than the other two products?

Observed Data:

$n = 450$ `//Total # people who bought Hershey's products (i.e., sample size)`

- **Total:** 450
- Reese's (R): 173 ($\frac{173}{n} = 38.44\%$)
- Kisses (K): 149 ($\frac{149}{n} = 33.11\%$)
- Whoppers (W): 128 ($\frac{128}{n} = 28.44\%$)

$p = 33.33\%$ `//Claim Percentage (i.e., equal share among products)`

$\sigma = \sqrt{\frac{p(1 - p)}{n}} = \sqrt{\frac{0.3333(1 - 0.3333)}{450}} = 2.22\%$ `//Standard deviation`

We then plot the above values to a normal distribution chart (claim percentage being the mean, and then +- 2 standard deviations) -- you can view the chart image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VeOc.jpg

From this we can see that only Kisses (K) falls within the likely 95% region, and so we can conclude that the three products are **not equally popular** with customers (at a 5% level of significance).

Obviously it appears as if Reese's are more popular, however the question is whether we can actually make any determination from this about Reese's being **more popular than the other two brands**. Can you test more than one thing at a time? How would we test whether one product is more popular than two others? Wouldn't we need a different claim percentage? If so, what might that be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can, using a *Chi Square Test* you can test for equality of each proportion where your Null Hypothesis would be Ho: P1 = P2 =...Pk (however many proportions your using, in this case 3), so your Null Hypothesis becomes Ho: P1 = P2 = P3. Now, your Alternative Hypothesis would be something like "At least one proportion is different" (you can be more specific than this). I would have commented this rather than posting as an "answer" because its more like a hint, but my reputation is so low I cannot make comments yet.

I'm going to assume you know a little about the Chi Square, but if you don't just do a simple google search..You already have your "Observed Counts" which is the Reeses = 173, Kisses = 149 and Whoppers = 128.. The 33% is very important because this is the percentage we use to calculate the "Expected Counts". You just multiply the total sample size by this, so 450*(1/3) = 150. So of 450 samples you would "expect" about 150 for each...Using these 2 values: "Observed Count" and "Expected Count", you can plug them into the Chi Square Formula and eventually obtain a p-value.. I don't have enough experience here to post the formulas super nice for you, but I will leave that to you to figure out :p

If you don't have statistical software such as "R" or a graphing calculator.. this is a useful link.. http://www.chisquarecalculator.com/